# redux how to get or store computed values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How should I implement in redux computed values based on it's current state?

I have this for an example a sessionState

```
const defaultState = {
  ui: {
    loading: false
  }, metadata: { },
  data: {
    id: null
  }
}

export default function sessionReducer(state = defaultState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case STORE_DATA:
    return _.merge({}, state, action.data);
  case PURGE_DATA:
    return defaultState;
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

Say for example I want to get if the session is logged in, I usually do right now is `sessionState.data.id` to check it, but I want to know how I can do `sessionState.loggedIn` or something?

Can this do?

```
const defaultState = {
  ui: {
    loading: false
  }, metadata: { },
  data: {
    id: null
  },
  loggedIn: () => {
    this.data.id
  }
}
```

or something (that's not tested, just threw that in). In this example it looks simple to just write `.data.id` but maybe when it comes to computations already, it's not good to write the same computations on different files.

Comment: Have a look at [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect).

Answer (score 2):

Adding methods to state object is a bad idea. State should be plain objects. Keep in mind, that some libraries serialize the app state on every mutation.

You can create computing functions outside the state object. They can receive state as an argument. Why should they be state's methods?

```
const defaultState = {
  ui: {
    loading: false
  }, metadata: { },
  data: {
    id: null
  }  
}


 const loggedIn = (state) => {
   //your logic here
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example, the calculated result is incredibly simple and fast to calculate so you can calculate it on demand each time. This makes it easy to define a function somewhere to calculate it like @Lazarev suggested.

However, if your calculations become more complicated and time consuming, you'll want to store the result somewhere so you can reuse it. Putting this data in the state is not a good idea because it denormalizes the state.

Luckily, since the state is immutable, you can write a simple pure function to calculate a result and then you can use [memoization](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoizee) to cache the result:

```
const isLoggedIn = memoize(state => state.login.userName && state.login.token && isValidToken (state.login.token));
```

Lastly, if you want to use methods on your store state, you can use [Redux Schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-schema) (disclaimer: I wrote it):

```
const storeType = reduxSchema.type({
  ui: {
    loading: Boolean
  }, metadata: { },
  data: {
    id: reduxSchema.optional(String)
  },
  loggedIn() {
    return Boolean(this.data.id);
  }
});
```

Comment: I agree completely, except that there is a 'memoize' library specifically written for immutable data structures, https://github.com/louisremi/memoize-immutable